# Possible to write Regex for fixed width file?

Tags: regex, fixed-length-record, fixed-length-file

I have been receiving fixed width file in which I need to filter out some of the values.

Ex, String contains value mentioned below. I want to separate out 3 fields from it (from 1st to 2nd, 3rd to 7th and 8th to 10th)

```
Input value -->  AA123X45ZZ

Output : 
field 1 --> AA 
field 2 --> 123X4 
field 3 --> 5ZZ
```

1. Is this possible via regex? I tried out different regex but was not able to generate regex for fixed-width string.

Edit :

2. Is that possible to discard 1st and 3rd field and only get 2nd as output of regex?
   In above example if input string is "AA123X45ZZ", so output would be "123X4".

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: It can be done. All inputs respect that lenght?

Comment: You can use `^(..)(.{5})(.{3})$` and grab group1 group2 and group3

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.` (dot):

```
^(..)(.....)(...)
```

All characters after are ignored.

Comment: Is that possible to discard 1st and 3rd field and only get 2nd as a output of regex?
In above example if input string is "AA123X45ZZ", so output would be "123X4".